# Purpose of com.ibm.oti.vm.bootstrap.library.path on AIX j9vm JVM

Tags: jvm, aix, jvm-arguments

## Background

I have a C++ program that loads a JVM internally and then uses JNI to call code in the JVM. This runs on multiple platforms including AIX. However, when starting the JVM on AIX everything is fine until I call some code that needs to access native code supplied as part of the JRE. I then run into this error message:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: net (Not found in com.ibm.oti.vm.bootstrap.library.path)
```

The problem is that the JVM cannot find the shared library `libnet.so`. If I dump the value of the `com.ibm.oti.vm.bootstrap.library.path` system property from Java code running in the JVM I see that by default (i.e. not me setting it) it has the value:

```
<jre-base-dir>/lib/ppc/default:<jre-base-dir>/lib/ppc
```

From the error message I guessed it would be a good idea to change this to include the dir where `libnet.so` is located. However, this shared library is in `<jre-base-dir>/lib/ppc` which is already in the path set by `com.ibm.oti.vm.bootstrap.library.path`, so it seems the error message is incorrect.

Experimenting with different values for this system property makes me believe that it is used by the AIX j9vm to load the internal JVM shared libraries only (like `libjclse7b_26.so`) but not the native code implementations (like `libnet.so`).

## My fix

To fix my problem I had to change the `LIBPATH` environment variable (which is AIX the equivalent of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in e.g. Linux).

```
$ LIBPATH=<jre-base-dir>/lib/ppc:<jre-base-dir>/lib/ppc/j9vm ./myprogram
```

## Questions

1. Can anyone shed some light on the real purpose of the system property `com.ibm.oti.vm.bootstrap.library.path` on AIX when using the j9vm JVM?
2. Is my fix the correct way to solve the problem or should I use some other system property? (I have tried `java.library.path` but it does not seem to help.)

Comment: What version of Java do you use? We have following exception "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: fontmanager (Not found in com.ibm.oti.vm.bootstrap.library.path)". But your fix does not work for us. We use IBM Java 1.6 SR14.

Comment: Here is the version info: $ ./java -version ↵
java version "1.7.0" ↵
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pap3270sr5-20130619_01(SR5)) ↵
IBM J9 VM (build 2.6, JRE 1.7.0 AIX ppc-32 20130617_152572 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled) ↵
J9VM - R26_Java726_SR5_20130617_1436_B152572 ↵
JIT  - r11.b04_20130528_38954ifx1 ↵
GC   - R26_Java726_SR5_20130617_1436_B152572 ↵
J9CL - 20130617_152572) ↵
JCL - 20130616_01 based on Oracle 7u25-b12

Answer (score 1):

In my case it show error message:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: awt (Not found in com.ibm.oti.vm.bootstrap.library.path)

I fix my problem by 
copy  /usr/java6_64/jre/lib/ppc64/libawt.so to /usr/java6_64/jre/lib/ppc64/j9vm and create symbolic link libawt.a to libawt.so

I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/java6_64/jre/lib/ppc64:/usr/java6_64/jre/lib/ppc64/j9vm"; export LD_
LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: I would prefer a solution where you don't modify the JRE distribution. Did you try my solution before copying files and creating symlinks?

Comment: I try but it does not work for me.The easy solution that work for me is to create only symbolic link between /usr/java6_64/jre/lib/ppc64/j9vm/libawt.so and /usr/java6_64/jre/lib/ppc64/libawt.so.

Comment: Ok, but your answer does not really answer my question where I ask for insight into the purpose of com.ibm.oti.vm.bootstrap.library.path